# hide one div and show the other

Tags: javascript, css

Im trying to set one div to none and another to block so one disappears, and the other is gonna show. but when i run the code it says: Can not read property 'style' of null. I am still a beginner but i really do not know what i am doing wrong here

```
function test(div1,div2)  
{  
    var= d1 = document.getElementById(div1);  
    var= d2 = document.getElementById(div2);  
    if( d2.style.display == "none" )  
   {  
    d1.style.display = "none";  
    d2.style.display = "block";  
   }  
    else  
   {  
    d1.style.display = "block";  
    d2.style.display = "none";  
   }  
}
```

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id= "div1"> 
    <h1>Hoi ik ben een div<h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div id= "div2">
    <h2>hoi ik ben 2e div<h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<button onclick="test()">click</button>

</body>
</html>
```

> CSS

```
#div1{
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    background-color: blue;
}
#div2{
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: green;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Use `onclick="test('div1', 'div2')"` . If you don't know why that works, I suggest some basic Javascript / CSS tutorial, you can find lots of them online.

Answer (score 0):

call function as

```
test('div1','div2')
```

or change this

```
var= d1 = document.getElementById(div1);  
var= d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
```

to this

```
var d1 = document.getElementById('div1');  
var d2 = document.getElementById('div2');
```

In either case you must change `var=` to `var`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test()  
{  
    var d1 = document.getElementById("div1");  
    var d2 = document.getElementById("div2");  
    if( d2.style.display == "none" )  
   {  
    d1.style.display = "none";  
    d2.style.display = "block";  
   }  
    else  
   {  
    d1.style.display = "block";  
    d2.style.display = "none";  
   }  
}
```

Here after read the error messages carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look:

```js
const toggleDiv = (div1,div2) => {  
  const d1 = document.getElementById(div1);  
  const d2 = document.getElementById(div2);  
  if( d2.style.display === "none" ){  
    d1.style.display = "none";  
    d2.style.display = "block";  
  }  
  else {  
    d1.style.display = "block";  
    d2.style.display = "none";  
  }  
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

<div id="div2">Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.</div>

<button onclick="toggleDiv('div1', 'div2')">Click to Toggole</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all good topic to start. This is not answer for your question, but when I saw your question I was thinking what is this simple problems solution. What would I do if I were? Here is my answer to that question.

First I assume there can be multiple options to toggle, and there can be multiple groups to toggle. Here is html;

```
<div class="toggle-item first-active">
    item 1
</div>
<div class="toggle-item">
    item 2
</div>
<div class="toggle-item">
    item 3
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="toggleGroup('toggle-item')">Toggle Group 1</button>

<div class="toggle-item-other first-active">
    item 4
</div>
<div class="toggle-item-other">
    item 5
</div>
<div class="toggle-item-other">
    item 6
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="toggleGroup('toggle-item-other')">Toggle Group 2</button>
```

And here is css code

```
<style>
.toggle-item:not(.first-active),
.toggle-item-other:not(.first-active){
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

and here is the javascript code:

```
<script>
var activeGroups = {}; //to keep active Indexes of groups

function toggleGroup(itemGroup){
    activeItemIndex = (activeGroups[itemGroup] || 0) + 1; //index +1
    var itemGroupElements = document.querySelectorAll('.' + itemGroup); //all group items
    activeItemIndex = activeItemIndex % itemGroupElements.length; //lets work forever
    for(var i=0; i < itemGroupElements.length; i++){
        itemGroupElements[i].style.display = i==activeItemIndex ? 'block' : 'none'; //hide items if not active index and show item active index
    }
    activeGroups[itemGroup] = activeItemIndex; //keep active item for next click
}
</script>
```

and that's my solution to same problem. Good luck!